# WCF data insertion fails

Tags: silverlight, wcf, entity-framework

I have a Silverlight application that connects to a remote server. I am using EF + WCF for database connection. I can retrieve data with no problem, but if I want to insert a new entry to the table, I get the following exception:

```
[HttpWebRequest_WebException_RemoteServer]
Arguments: NotFound
```

And then there is a lot of stack trace information that is not directly related to my code. Here is how the WCF service adds a new entry:

```
[OperationContract]   
public void addNewEntry(INFORMATION info)
{
      myDBEntities en = new myDBEntities();
      en.AddToINFORMATION(info);
      en.SaveChanges();
}
```

I pass an INFORMATION object from the client to the service which attempts to save the new entry to the table. The object itself is properly constructed.

What am I doing wrong? I don't understand why I can retrieve data but not save any.

Comment: And what exception do you get on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be several things:

- You are in the security context of a user that is allowed to get data, but not save data
- There is a required field in the table that you are not sending in

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other comments, why do you have your database logic in the [OperationContract] method.

You should abstract the business / database logic into different classes / assemblies...food for thought.